# ORDER BY money type in PostgreSQL: Trailing zeros

Tags: postgresql

In my table I have some field 'price' with `money` type.

I need to make order from price, from lower to higher, but I need to collect all zero-values in the end.

Is it possible to do in one request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two sort criteria, e.g.:

```
order by val = 0, val
```